# GetElementById/GetElementsByTagName not finding element

Tags: html, vb.net

Bear in mind that I know only a bit about HTML:

There is a site I'm trying to interact with using a WebBrowser. The site has a textarea element as follows:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$txtCallDesc" rows="2" cols="20" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_txtCallDesc" tabindex="205" style="width: 100%; height: 80px; font-size: 8pt"></textarea>
```

From what I've read, the generated ID of the textarea signifies that it's placed inside another form of some sort, and I'm not sure if this is where I'm running into my problem.

Once the page has loaded, I have something like the following in a button:

```
Dim theCol As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theCol
    ListBox1.Items.Add(curElement.TagName)
Next
```

Nothing populates in the list. I've also tried using the ID of the text box gathered by the 'inspect element' feature of Chrome:

```
Dim value As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_txtCallDesc")
MsgBox(value.GetAttribute("value"))
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the program to recognize that there ARE textarea elements in the document. The source for the page is far to long to spam everyone with here, but is there anything I'm missing that I should be looking out for? Perhaps needing to get another element first, then search that for elements within it?

**Edit:**

The element I'm trying to get seems to be within an iFrame, but it looks like it's from the same domain so the same origin policy shouldn't come into play, should it?

```
<iframe id="mainFrame" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" class="mainFrame" name="Main" src="/Calls/OpenCalls.aspx">
```

Comment: Yeah -- as I said in the post, the code to get the elements are in a button that's separate to make sure I give it plenty of time to finish loading. I just can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: In order for you to find the id in code behind, the textarea needs runat="server". If you cannot change the code, use javascript to find it, then pass off the value to your code behind

Comment: @Cory, could you point me in the right direction to learn how to go about doing that? The webpage isn't one I can edit. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code shown in [Get Iframe HTML](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?621913-Get-Iframe-HTML):

```
For i = 0 To WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames.Count - 1
    Dim frameDoc = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames(i)

    Dim theCol = frameDoc.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")

    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theCol
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("TagName: {0} Id:{1}", curElement.TagName, curElement.Id))
    Next

Next
```

The essential part being the use of [WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.frames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference elements inside an iframe directly since they are inside another document.  So first get a reference to the document element inside the iframe and then you can query it the same way.

```
Dim frameDoc = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainFrame").DomElement.contentWindow.Docume‌​nt
```

And the rest you already know...

```
Dim theCol = frameDoc.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
For Each curElement In theCol
    ListBox1.Items.Add(curElement.TagName)
Next
```

Comment: I tried this (only using .Document since .contentDocument didn't seem to be a valid variable), and the listbox still didn't populate. Looping through elements in frameDoc.all didn't return anything either, so I'm not sure where the kinks are.

Comment: Temporarily set `OPTION STRICT OFF` and test with `.contentDocument`. It should work. You would need appropriate typecasting when it is on.

Comment: Even with OPTION STRICT OFF, a compile-time error says: 'contentDocument' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'.

Comment: I'm not anywhere near my PC, so can't test it. What happens if you do `Dim frameDoc = Ctype (WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainFrame") , Object).contentDocument` while still option strict off.

Comment: That lets it compile, but throws a MissingMemberException during runtime; `Public member 'contentDocument' on type 'HtmlElement' not found.`

Comment: Try: `Dim frameDoc = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainFrame").DomElement.contentWindow.Document`

Comment: Tested and updated the code. However, Andrew Morton's answer is still better than this, since it doesn't need late binding.